# Error while running Neo4j: Not possible to upgrade a store with version 'v0.A.9' to current store version `v0.A.8` (Neo4j 3.3.1)

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to run neo4j 3.3.1 while I am getting the following error:

```
2018-05-29 08:43:36.805+0000 INFO  Starting upgrade of database
2018-05-29 08:43:36.815+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@6c2c1385' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Not possible to upgrade a store with version 'v0.A.9' to current store version `v0.A.8` (Neo4j 3.3.1).". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@6c2c1385' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Not possible to upgrade a store with version 'v0.A.9' to current store version `v0.A.8` (Neo4j 3.3.1).".
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@6c2c1385' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Not possible to upgrade a store with version 'v0.A.9' to current store version `v0.A.8` (Neo4j 3.3.1).".
    at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:219)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:32)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@6c2c1385' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Not possible to upgrade a store with version 'v0.A.9' to current store version `v0.A.8` (Neo4j 3.3.1).".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:211)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /home/ubuntu/.ineo/instances/staging1/data/databases/graph.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:211)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:126)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$0(CommunityNeoServer.java:58)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@60129b9a' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Not possible to upgrade a store with version 'v0.A.9' to current store version `v0.A.8` (Neo4j 3.3.1).".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:100)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:207)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnexpectedUpgradingStoreVersionException: Not possible to upgrade a store with version 'v0.A.9' to current store version `v0.A.8` (Neo4j 3.3.1).
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradableDatabase.checkUpgradeable(UpgradableDatabase.java:122)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:132)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.DatabaseMigrator.migrate(DatabaseMigrator.java:101)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.upgradeStore(NeoStoreDataSource.java:573)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:435)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    ... 14 more
2018-05-29 08:43:36.819+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
```

I generated my graph.db using neo4j-admin import command. I also changed the dbms.allow_upgrade=true as suggested by logs. What is the problem here and how should I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Actually I created the graph.db using version 3.4.0 and was trying to run using 3.3.1. When i tried running it with 3.4.0, it worked!