# Not possible to upgrade a store with version 'v0.A.3' to current store version `v0.A.9` (Neo4j 3.4.6) - dataset example related

Tags: neo4j

I am working through `Neo4j` section of Seven Databases in Seven Weeks book. I am at the Big Data section of day 2. I was able to download and move the Movie Database dataset example (`cineasts_12k_movies_50k_actors.db`) to `data/databases`. I then comment out `dbms.active_database=graph.db` and added the line

```
dbms.active_database=movies.db
```

in `neo4j.conf` file in `/conf folder`.

According to the instruction in the book, I ought to go into same file (`neo4j.conf`) to uncomment the line:

```
#dbms.allow_format_migrations=true
```

but such line did not exist in the file. And adding it to the config file threw up below error:

```
C:\Users\w3s\Desktop\NEO4J_HOME\neo4j-enterprise-3.4.6-windows\neo4j-enterprise-
3.4.6\bin>neo4j console
2018-08-24 03:37:28.996+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: dbms.allow_format_migr
ations
2018-08-24 03:37:29.076+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.4.6 ========
2018-08-24 03:37:29.170+0000 INFO  Starting...
2018-08-24 03:37:33.672+0000 INFO  Initiating metrics...
2018-08-24 03:37:34.180+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed:
 Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@6db66836' was su
ccessfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause excep
tion "Unknown store version 'v0.A.3'". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo
4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@6db66836' was successfully initiali
zed, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unknown store
 version 'v0.A.3'".
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.n
eo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@6db66836' was successfully initia
lized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unknown sto
re version 'v0.A.3'".
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStart
upError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:220)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111
)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)

        at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.CommercialEntryPoint.main(CommercialEntry
Point.java:22)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.s
erver.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@6db66836' was successfully initialized,
 but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unknown store ver
sion 'v0.A.3'".
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSu
pport.java:466)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:212)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.fact
ory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, C:\Users\w3s\Desktop\NEO4J_HOME\neo4j-enterprise
-3.4.6-windows\neo4j-enterprise-3.4.6\data\databases\movies.db
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(G
raphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:212)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.enterprise.EnterpriseGraphDatabase.<init>(Enterprise
GraphDatabase.java:39)
        at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.lambda$static$1(O
penEnterpriseNeoServer.java:78)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleMa
nagingDatabase.java:88)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSu
pport.java:445)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.k
ernel.NeoStoreDataSource@4152d38d' was successfully initialized, but failed to s
tart. Please see the attached cause exception "Unknown store version 'v0.A.3'".
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSu
pport.java:466)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataS
ourceManager.java:100)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSu
pport.java:445)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(G
raphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:208)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown store version 'v0.A.3'
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.format.RecordFormatSelector.selectForVers
ion(RecordFormatSelector.java:101)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.verifyRecordFormat(NeoStores.ja
va:211)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.<init>(NeoStores.java:143)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openNeoStores(StoreFactory.j
ava:160)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openAllNeoStores(StoreFactor
y.java:124)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageE
ngine.<init>(RecordStorageEngine.java:200)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.buildStorageEngine(NeoStoreDataSo
urce.java:574)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:434
)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSu
pport.java:445)
        ... 14 more
2018-08-24 03:37:34.183+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
```

From online research, it seemed it (`#dbms.allow_format_migrations=true`) was a depreciated config option. I then went to the A.1. Configuration settings at https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/ and from what I could make out there it seemed (my own conclusion) I could just uncomment `dbms.allow_upgrade` in place of `dbms.allow_format_migrations` (which was not available/ now depreciated) but I get below error:

```
C:\Users\w3s\Desktop\NEO4J_HOME\neo4j-enterprise-3.4.6-windows\neo4j-enterprise-
3.4.6\bin>neo4j console
2018-08-24 03:42:32.958+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.4.6 ========
2018-08-24 03:42:33.031+0000 INFO  Starting...
2018-08-24 03:42:36.413+0000 INFO  Initiating metrics...
2018-08-24 03:42:36.787+0000 INFO  Starting upgrade of database
2018-08-24 03:42:36.807+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed:
 Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@759fad4' was suc
cessfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause except
ion "Not possible to upgrade a store with version 'v0.A.3' to current store vers
ion `v0.A.9` (Neo4j 3.4.6).". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server
.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@759fad4' was successfully initialized, but f
ailed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Not possible to upgrade
 a store with version 'v0.A.3' to current store version `v0.A.9` (Neo4j 3.4.6)."
.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.n
eo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@759fad4' was successfully initial
ized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Not possible
 to upgrade a store with version 'v0.A.3' to current store version `v0.A.9` (Neo
4j 3.4.6).".
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStart
upError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:220)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111
)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)

        at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.CommercialEntryPoint.main(CommercialEntry
Point.java:22)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.s
erver.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@759fad4' was successfully initialized,
but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Not possible to up
grade a store with version 'v0.A.3' to current store version `v0.A.9` (Neo4j 3.4
.6).".
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSu
pport.java:466)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:212)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.fact
ory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, C:\Users\w3s\Desktop\NEO4J_HOME\neo4j-enterprise
-3.4.6-windows\neo4j-enterprise-3.4.6\data\databases\movies.db
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(G
raphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:212)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.enterprise.EnterpriseGraphDatabase.<init>(Enterprise
GraphDatabase.java:39)
        at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.lambda$static$1(O
penEnterpriseNeoServer.java:78)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleMa
nagingDatabase.java:88)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSu
pport.java:445)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.k
ernel.NeoStoreDataSource@cf65451' was successfully initialized, but failed to st
art. Please see the attached cause exception "Not possible to upgrade a store wi
th version 'v0.A.3' to current store version `v0.A.9` (Neo4j 3.4.6).".
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSu
pport.java:466)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataS
ourceManager.java:100)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSu
pport.java:445)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(G
raphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:208)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnexpectedUpgradin
gStoreVersionException: Not possible to upgrade a store with version 'v0.A.3' to
 current store version `v0.A.9` (Neo4j 3.4.6).
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradableDatabase.checkUpgradea
ble(UpgradableDatabase.java:122)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateStore(Store
Upgrader.java:141)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(St
oreUpgrader.java:122)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.DatabaseMigrator.migrate(Databas
eMigrator.java:100)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.upgradeStore(NeoStoreDataSource.j
ava:564)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:419
)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSu
pport.java:445)
        ... 14 more
2018-08-24 03:42:36.810+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
```

Then, I commented out the line 'dbms.allow_upgrade' and ran neo4j console again to start server on cmd and got below error:

```
C:\Users\w3s\Desktop\NEO4J_HOME\neo4j-enterprise-3.4.6-windows\neo4j-enterprise-
3.4.6\bin>neo4j console
2018-08-24 03:49:20.922+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.4.6 ========
2018-08-24 03:49:21.008+0000 INFO  Starting...
2018-08-24 03:49:24.533+0000 INFO  Initiating metrics...
2018-08-24 03:49:25.557+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j 

failed:
     Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@9cd25ff' was suc
    cessfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause except
    ion "Unknown store version 'v0.A.3'". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4
    j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@9cd25ff' was successfully initialize
    d, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unknown store v
    ersion 'v0.A.3'".
    org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.n
    eo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@9cd25ff' was successfully initial
    ized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unknown stor
    e version 'v0.A.3'".
            at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStart
    upError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
            at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:220)
            at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111
    )
            at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)

            at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.CommercialEntryPoint.main(CommercialEntry
    Point.java:22)
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.s
    erver.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@9cd25ff' was successfully initialized,
    but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unknown store vers
    ion 'v0.A.3'".
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSu
    pport.java:466)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
            at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:212)
            ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.fact
    ory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, C:\Users\w3s\Desktop\NEO4J_HOME\neo4j-enterprise
    -3.4.6-windows\neo4j-enterprise-3.4.6\data\databases\movies.db
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(G
    raphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:212)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.enterprise.EnterpriseGraphDatabase.<init>(Enterprise
    GraphDatabase.java:39)
            at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.lambda$static$1(O
    penEnterpriseNeoServer.java:78)
            at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleMa
    nagingDatabase.java:88)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSu
    pport.java:445)
            ... 5 more
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.k
    ernel.NeoStoreDataSource@7a11c4c7' was successfully initialized, but failed to s
    tart. Please see the attached cause exception "Unknown store version 'v0.A.3'".
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSu
    pport.java:466)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataS
    ourceManager.java:100)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSu
    pport.java:445)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(G
    raphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:208)
            ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown store version 'v0.A.3'
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.format.RecordFormatSelector.selectForVers
    ion(RecordFormatSelector.java:101)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.verifyRecordFormat(NeoStores.ja
    va:211)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.<init>(NeoStores.java:143)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openNeoStores(StoreFactory.j
    ava:160)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openAllNeoStores(StoreFactor
    y.java:124)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageE
    ngine.<init>(RecordStorageEngine.java:200)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.buildStorageEngine(NeoStoreDataSo
    urce.java:574)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:434
    )
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSu
    pport.java:445)
            ... 14 more
    2018-08-24 03:49:25.563+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
```

Please advise on way around this so I can work with the example dataset (and then carry forward to practice with other example datasets).
Thanks a loaded bunch for your time.

NOTE: I run a windows 7 OS machine; my version of `neo4j` is the `trial neo4j-enterprise-3.4.6`; I use `cygwin` terminal alongside `cmd` prompt to follow along with the book; I am a beginner programmer (I don't know much). Also, this [Error while running Neo4j: Not possible to upgrade a store with version 'v0.A.9' to current store version `v0.A.8` (Neo4j 3.3.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580205/error-while-running-neo4j-not-possible-to-upgrade-a-store-with-version-v0-a-9) seemed similar but was not helpful (no answers there).

Comment: I was facing the same problem. The problem here is that the dataset given on the page https://neo4j.com/developer/movie-database/ causes this issue. If you download the movie database from this page: https://neo4j.com/developer/example-data/, then this one works.

Answer (score 2):

I think this issue was caused by version compatibility of neo4j.
See https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/store-format-versions/   .

And there are two solutions for this issue. One solution is downgrading the version of neo4j you used to 2.1.0. Another is upgrading your data manually to 0.A.8.

Good luck!